# SQL Server : performance issue with ROW_NUMBER OVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a performance issue that I'm trying to sort out and I'm looking for advice. I have a view (see below) that needs to work across hundreds of thousands of rows, and I'm trying to make it faster. I've cleaned things up to take out the context and add data types. Just looking for ideas.

```
SELECT 
    i.*, 
    gci.String1, gci.String2, gci.String3,
    v.String4, v.Guid1
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         c.*, t.Bit1, t.Guid2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.Guid2, t.Guid1, c.String5 ORDER BY t.Weight DESC) [Rank]
     FROM 
         Table5 c
     INNER JOIN
         Table4 t ON c.Guid3 = t.Guid3 
                  AND c.Int1 = t.Int1 
                  AND ((t.String6 = c.String6) OR
                       (t.String7 = c.String7) OR
                       (t.String6 IS NULL AND t.String7 IS NULL))) i
INNER JOIN
    Table3 vf ON i.Guid3 = vf.Guid3
INNER JOIN
    Table2 v ON vf.Guid1 = v.Guid1
LEFT JOIN
    Table1 gci ON i.String5 = gci.String5 
               AND v.Guid1 = gci.Guid1
WHERE
    i.[Rank] = 1
```

My only thought was to somehow (and I have specific ideas that aren't relative to my question) replace `String5` with `Int2` (a new column).

That way, the `OVER` wouldn't have to group by a `nvarchar` (instead an `int`) and could be faster. Maybe?

I have individual indexes on all of the relevant columns:

**Table1**

- Guid1, String5 (non-clustered two-column primary key)

**Table2**

- Guid1 (non-clustered primary key)

**Table3**

- Guid1 (index), Guid3 (non-clustered primary key)

**Table4**

- Guid1 (index), Guid2 (index), Guid3 (index), Int1 (index), String6 (index), String7 (index)

**Table5**

- Guid3 (index), Int1 (index), String6 (index), String7 (index), String5 (index)

`Table5` is the one with all of the rows and is just joined across the others, which are relatively small. It just magnifies for each of the rows in each of the others - especially `Table4`.

Thoughts or ideas? Something that I can try without blowing up my database structure?

Comment: Create indexes on fields t.Guid2, t.Guid1, t.Weight.

Comment: CREATE INDEX IX33etcc ON Table4 (Guid2, Guid1, Weight, etcc) and check the performance in this case.

Comment: What's the query plan? Or how do you know this view is a problem?

Comment: I doubt it will help any to change the datatype of the ROW_NUMBER OVER parts. You could junk the GUIDs and create INT keys instead

Comment: We gotta see the execution plan else we're just throwing guesses at you.

Comment: Share the actual execution plan at [Paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan). Sorting by guids is not going to be helping performance here (partitions require sorted data). See [How to get SQL Server Performance question help](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Answer (score 1):

In my Experience using OR operator in the JOIN condition can lead to performance issues. Depending on your data maybe you can try to get rid of the OR and maybe split the join.